# JQuery click function order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know how can I change the background-image of another div element, when I click on it. I would like to see images one after another in order but what I get is the last one. Here is some code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // console.log('ready!');

    $('.right').click(function () {
        $('.zur-gda-img').css('background','url(images/sail-boat.jpg)');
    }).click(function() {
        $('.zur-gda-img').css('background','url(images/sad_ostateczny.jpg)');
    }) }).click(function() {
        $('.zur-gda-img').css('background','url(images/twierdza_wisloujscie.jpg)');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding multiple event handler use single. Inside handler change images from the array with help of a counter variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // store images in an array
  var images = ['url(images/sail-boat.jpg)', 'url(images/sad_ostateczny.jpg)', 'url(images/twierdza_wisloujscie.jpg)'],
    //  variable to store index  
    i = 0;
  $('.right').click(function() {
    // update index based on array length
    i = i % images.length;
    // update background from array using the index value
    $('.zur-gda-img').css('background', images[i++]);
  })
});
```

Comment: Why do you need `i = i % images.length`?

Comment: @gcampbell : just to rollback to the  `0th` index position

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, I realised that.

Comment: @LukaszKisicki : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need three event handlers for this (they will just fire one after another and you'll only see the last image). If you want to see images changing, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // document has loaded

    $('.right').click(function () {
        // 1st image:
        $('.zur-gda-img').css('background','url(images/sail-boat.jpg)');

        // 2nd image, appears in a second:
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.zur-gda-img').css('background','url(images/sad_ostateczny.jpg)');

            // 3rd image, appears in another second:
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.zur-gda-img').css('background','url(images/twierdza_wisloujscie.jpg)');
            },
            1000);
        },
        1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand question as it but it could be it indeed

Comment: @A.Wolff author didn't elaborate on what "I would like to see images one after another in order" means, so either of 2 answers could be correct :)

Comment: thanks I might use your solution for time intervals that I plan to add